# Render JSP in Tornado

Tags: jsp, tornado

In tornado I used self.render to include a html file.
I used self.render(welcome.html) , where welcome is the name of the html file.

My question is how to include JSP file in Tornado?

Comment: Are you aware that JSP page requires Java servlet engine (e.g. Tomcat) to run? Btw. you should share your code.

Answer (score 0):

To include jsp file:

self.render(name of the file)